# How to transfer information from two lists in an alternating manner into multiple JSON objects?

Tags: python, json, list, object

I have two lists in Python that need their content to be transferred into a series of JSON objects that needs to be printed out to a file. The contents need to be included in an alternating manner with one number and one letter per JSON object. I've attached a simplified version of what I need.

E.g. lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Desired output:

```
{
   "item1": {
       "number": "1",
       "letter": "a"
   },
   "item2": {
       "number": "2",
       "letter": "b"
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to bind together the corresponding elements of `list1` and `list2`. Then, you can use a dict comprehension to build the data structure you describe, and `json.dumps()` to easily convert it to JSON.

```
my_dict = {
    f"item{number}" : {
        "number": number,
        "letter": letter,
    } 
    for (number, letter) in zip(list1, list2)
}

json.dumps(my_dict)
# '{"item1": {"number": 1, "letter": "a"}, "item2": {"number": 2, "letter": "b"}, "item3": {"number": 3, "letter": "c"}, "item4": {"number": 4, "letter": "d"}, "item5": {"number": 5, "letter": "e"}}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I need ```itemOne``` instead of item1, how can I do this? The values ```One, Two, Three, etc.``` would also be from another list

Comment: @awdoibbbbbbb2 You can `zip()` together as many lists as you want, and use an f-string like is being done here to insert it wherever you need.